# example of a set that is closed and bounded but not compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Find an example of a subset $S$ of a metric space such that $S$ is closed and bounded but not compact.

One such example that comes from analysis is probably a closed and bounded set in $C[0,1]$. I attempt to construct my own example to see if it works.

Is $\{ \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ endowed with discrete topology a set that is closed and bounded but not compact? My guess is that it is indeed an example of closed and bounded does not imply compact.

Every element is less than or equal to $1$, and it is closed  as a whole set. If we let $\mathcal{A}$ be a covering of the set that consists of singletons in $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$ so that any finite subcover

$\{ \frac{1}{n_j} |j =1,...,k \quad \text{and} \quad n_j \in \mathbb{N} \}$ will not cover $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, because if we take $n = \max \{{n_j}\}, \frac{1}{n+1}$ is not in the finite subcover.

Thanks in advance for pointing out any mistake.

Comment: You specified the topology on $X=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Are you treating it just as a topological space? If so, what does it mean for a general topological space to be "bounded"? Perhaps you instead mean to let $X$ inherit the metric of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Neal yeah you are right about this. I was thinking I seem to be lacking something

Comment: Find a closed set that *isn't* bounded.....

Comment: Is your question about the Euclidean space or a generic metric space?

Comment: "in a certain metric space"  Which metric space?

Comment: A generic metric space.

Comment: I forgot to add "bounded" condition(((

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question.  The set integers is closed.  The collection of an infinite number of closed intervals, the entire space itself, An infinite combinations of singletons and closed intervals, etc. all work.

Comment: It does work for not bounded sets, but I wish to find a _bounded_ set(also closed) that is not compact...

Comment: So far I failed to construct an explicit one...

Comment: @TonyTong Changing the question after several answers have appeared is not proper. It will make all the answers look wrong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry for that.... I am a beginner in analysis, still struggling in these concepts...

Comment: "In Euclidean space closed and bounded sets are compact".  Not actually true.  Only in complete Euclidean spaces is this true.  In an *incomplete* Euclidean space such as $\mathbb Q$ this will not be true.

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space then the metric $e(x,y)=\min (1,d(x,y))$ generates the same topology on $X$ that $d$ does, so $d$ and $e$ produce the same open sets and closed sets. So any $S\subset X$ is compact in the space $(X,d)$ iff $S$ is compact in the space $(X,e)$. But every subset of $X$ is bounded with respect to $e.$ In particular if $(X,d)$ is  any non-compact metric space and $S=X$ then $S$ is a closed bounded non-compact subset in the space $(X,e).$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're on the right track. If we consider $X=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N^+\right\}$ in the discrete topology, then we can endow it with the metric $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ given by $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x=y\\1 & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ which does indeed induce the discrete topology on $X$ (it's called the *discrete metric* for this reason). Then $X$ is certainly bounded, as any ball of radius greater than $1$ necessarily includes the whole set, and is certainly closed **in itself** (as all spaces are). However, it is not compact, since the open cover by singletons admits no finite subcover, as you've observed. More generally, any infinite space with the discrete metric admits a proper subspace that is closed and bounded, but not compact (delete any point).

We could come to the same conclusions if we considered $X$ as a space under the metric $$\rho(x,y)=|x-y|.$$ Indeed, $\rho$ induces the discrete topology on $X$, as well, and we similarly find that $X$ is bounded under $\rho$.

On the other hand, suppose that $f:X\to\Bbb Z$ is a bijection, and define a function $m:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ by $$m(x,y):=\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|.$$ It turns out that, regardless of which bijection $f$ we use, the following hold:

- The function $m$ is a metric on $X.$
- The metric $m$ induces the discrete topology on $X,$ just as $d$ and $\rho$ do.
- The function $f$ is an *isometry* (distance-preserving isomorphism) from $X$ (under the metric $m$) to $\Bbb Z$ (under the metric $\rho$).
- As an immediate corollary to the third fact, $X$ is *not* bounded under the metric $m,$ despite the fact that it induces the same topology as the metrics $d$ and $\rho.$

The kicker, here, is the boundedness. You need to specify a metric, or some other convention to determine boundedness, not just a topology.

Comment: Is $S=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$? For the second example to work we need closeness, but the limit of the sequence $(1/n)$ is not in $S$.

Comment: No, $S$ is not closed in $\Bbb R,$ only in itself. If it *were* closed in $\Bbb R,$ then it would be compact, which it is not. The second "example" was just another way of exploring the same counterexample. Does that clear things up at all?

Comment: What was misleading for me is that the first example is closed (in itself) bounded and not compact; then you write "we could come to the same conclusion" and the example is not closed, bounded, not compact. My doubts are cleared, thank you.

Comment: I see! That phrasing was unclear. Hopefully, it is better now.

Answer (score 21):

If $\{e_n\}$ is an (infinite) orthonormal set in  a Hilbert space $H$ then  $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is closed and bounded but not compact. It is not compact because there is no convergent subsequence (since $\|e_n-e_m\|=\sqrt2$ for $n \neq  m)$.

Answer (score 16):

Let $X$ be a non compact metric space. Then $X$ is closed but not compact.

Comment: Oh that makes sense

Comment: Bruhh... I don't know why I find this so funny haha

Answer (score 12):

The "closed" ball $\lVert x \rVert \leq 1$ in any infinite dimensional Banach space is closed and bounded but not compact. It is closed because any point outside it is contained in a small open ball disjoint from the first one, by the triangle inequality. That is, if $\lVert y \rVert = 1 + 2 \delta,$ then the sets $\lVert x \rVert \leq 1$ and $\lVert x - y \rVert <  \delta$ are disjoint. Hence the complement of the "closed" unit ball is open and the  "closed" unit ball really is closed. But not compact if not in finite dimensions.

Comment: Since you proved in detail that the ball is closed, I hope you won't mind if I had this link: http://planetmath.org/CompactnessOfClosedUnitBallInNormedSpaces.html

Comment: @RudevanNistelrooy the link seems to be broken now...

Comment: @Julien, the link is broken. Can you find a current one?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, the link is moved to https://planetmath.org/compactnessofclosedunitballinnormedspaces

Answer (score 7):

Consider any infinite set $X$ with the metric $$d(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq y \\ 0 & x = y \end{cases} $$
This is called the discrete metric. Note that any $E \subseteq X$ is closed, open, and bounded, including $X$ itself. But $X$ is not compact. The open cover $\{ \{x\} : x \in X \}$ of $X$ by singletons had no finite subcover. Thus $X$ is not compact.

Comment: "But $X$ is not compact".  Nor is any infinite $E\subset X$.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, I just only pointed out $X$.

Comment: This is still a really good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if the metric space $X$ is unbounded take the complement of any bounded open set. For example $X$ itself which is the complement of the bounded open set $\emptyset$.

P.S. For your edited question, then $X$ has to be infinite-dimensional. If $X$ is a infinite-dimensional [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) then any closed ball of positive radius is closed, bounded but not compact.

Answer (score 4):

In any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ the closed unit ball $B(0,1)$ is closed but not compact (for the norm-topology).

*By $B(0,1)$  I mean the set $\{x\in\mathcal{H}: \ \Vert x\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}\leq 1\}$.

Note that for your edited question my previous answer still works. For any $y\in\mathcal{H}$ and any $r>0$ all the closed balls $B(y,r)=\{x\in\mathcal{H}:\ \Vert x-y\Vert\leq r\}$ are closed but not compact (as soon as $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite-dimensional).

Answer (score 4):

A metric space where closed, bounded $\iff$ compact is said to have the Heine-Borel property.  $\mathbb R^n$ with euclidean metric all have Heine-Borel property.

(Possibly) The easiest counter example of a metric space without the HB property, is probably $\mathbb Q^n$ as a euclidean metric space which, unlike $\mathbb R^n$ is not complete.

For example:  Consider $[1,\sqrt 2]\cap \mathbb Q = \{q\in \mathbb Q| q \ge 1; q^2 \le 2\}$.  In the metric space, $\mathbb Q$, this set is closed for the same reason $[1, \sqrt 2]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.  And it is bounded.

But it is not compact for the same reason $[1, \sqrt 2)$ is not compact in $\mathbb R$.  (Note:  $[1,\sqrt 2)\cap \mathbb Q = [1,\sqrt 2]\cap \mathbb Q$.)

(If you need more.  $\{(.9, \sqrt 2 -\frac 1n)\cap \mathbb Q|n\in \mathbb N\}$ is an open cover of $K =[1,\sqrt 2)\cap \mathbb Q = [1,\sqrt 2]\cap \mathbb Q$.  It has not finite sub cover.  This fails in $\mathbb R$ for $[1,\sqrt 2]$ because none of these open sets contain $\sqrt 2$.)

(And if you need to know why $K$ is closed in $\mathbb Q$.  Well, $\sqrt 2$ can't be a limit point as $\sqrt 2$ does not exist in $\mathbb Q$.)

It might be interesting to note that in $\mathbb R$ the only sets that are both open and closed are $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$.  But $\mathbb Q$ as a metric space, for any irrational $a,b: a < b$, that $[a,b]\cap \mathbb Q=(a,b)\cap \mathbb Q = \{q\in \mathbb Q| a < q < b\}$ are all both open and closed.

.....

A more complex space without the HB property is an infinite dimensional Banach space.  Infinite dimensions make a difference. As does lake of completeness.

....

When I said "easiest" I did forget about the discrete metric, as per AJYs terrific answer.

In the discrete metric space every set is both open and closed and as maximum distance is $1$ all sets are bounded.  And a singleton set of a single element is an open set.  So every set will have an open cover of singletons covering it and this cover will have no subcover.  So no infinite set is compact but all sets are closed and bounded.

That's arguably "easier" than $\mathbb Q^n$.... or maybe it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

$A=[0;1]∩\mathbb{Q}$ is bounded, closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not complete,as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so $A$ is not compact.

Comment: $\{(\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}) \cap \mathbb{Q}\}_{n =3,4,5, \ldots}$ is an open cover of $A$, however there is not a finite subcover of $A$. Hence $A$ is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here a more simple answer (from the point of view of an undergraduate student). I hope that it will help you or others.
We want to prove that $S= \left \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} | 1<r<2 \right \}$ is closed and bounded but not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ with the metric $d(x;y)=|x-y|$.

*1/$S$ is bounded.*
Indeed if we choose $r=4 \Rightarrow B(0;4)= \left \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} | d(0;r)<4 \right \}=\left \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} | |r|<4 \right \}$

*2/$S$ is closed.*
Lets use the sequencial caracterisation theorem. That means $\forall (u_n) \in E$ that converge to $l \in  \mathbb{Q}$ we have too that $l \in E$.
Indeed by contradiction if it not the case WLOG, $l>2$ by definitino for $\epsilon'= \frac{l-2}{4} \Rightarrow \exists N$ s.t.  all the $u_n$ with their $n>N$ will be in the intervall $(l - \epsilon' ; l + \epsilon')$. That means that an infinity of $u_n$ will not be in $S$.

*3/$S$ is not compact*
It can be shown that we can build a sequence $(u_n)$ in $S$ such that $u_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\rightarrow} \sqrt{2}$ (there is a lot of proof on the internet, it is called that the rationnal are dense in the real).

Q.E.D.