# Bounded and closed set, but not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, big-list

What kind of set if bounded and closed but not compact?

Edit for re-openers: re-tagged as [big-list](/questions/tagged/big-list).

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the Heine-Borel theorem says there are no such sets. Other topological spaces may have no notion of "boundedness" so the question depends on what space you look at.

Comment: potential dupe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323033/example-of-a-set-that-is-closed-and-bounded-but-not-compact?rq=1. also possibly edited to make it a [tag:big-list]

Answer (score 7):

By the Heine Borel theorem, you will need an example of a topological space that isn't simply a *closed* subset of $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual topology.

One example is $X = (0,1)$ with the topology inherited from $\Bbb R$.  In this example, $X$ is itself closed and bounded **within $X$**, but $X$ is not a compact space.

Another option is $\Bbb R$ with the discrete metric.  Any subset is closed, but any infinite subset fails to be compact.

Another classic example is $\Bbb R$ with the metric
$$
d(x,y) = \min\{|x - y|,1\}
$$
In this case, every subset is bounded, but not every subset is compact.

Comment: Your first sentence is not true.  The space can't be a **closed** subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with the usual topology, but a non-closed subset will do quite nicely.  Note that a closed and bounded set in the space need not be closed as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How is $X$ closed? $0$ and $1$ do not belong to $X$.

Comment: @Manjoy $X$ is not closed **as a subset of $\Bbb R$**. However, for any metric/topological space $X$, $X$ is a closed (and open) subset of itself.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the sequence space $\ell^\infty$ of bounded sequences with the norm
$$\|\|x\|\|_\infty = \sup_n |x_n|.$$

Let $e_n$ be the element of $\ell^\infty$ that is $1$ at $n$ and $0$ otherwise. The set of these is bounded. It is not compact because it is discrete and infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Take any metric space $X$ that is bounded but not compact, e.g. $(0,1)$ with the metric of $\mathbb R$.  Then $X$ itself is closed (in $X$) and bounded but not compact.

Alternatively, take any metric space $X$ that is not complete.  A Cauchy sequence in $X$ that does not converge is a set that is bounded and closed but not compact.

Answer (score 1):

The set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ with metric $d(p,q)=|p-q|$ has a subset $A=${$q\in \mathbb Q: 2\le q^2\le 4$}, which is closed and bounded but not compact due to the non-completeness of $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

If we are in a topological vector space (say, Banach), it has to be infinite-dimensional.  In subsets Euclidean spaces, closedness and boundedness are together equivalent to compactness.

Comment: We only need an infinite dimensional space if we want a normed vector space.

Comment: Wasn't sure the Asker is familiar with the more general topological spaces.  But, that makes my answer not quite accurate.  I'll revise.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology.
It is a metrizable space with the discrete metric induced from the topology.
Then the set $\mathbb R$ is a closed subset (since the whole space is always closed).
This set is also bounded because the distance between every 2 points in it is never more than 1.
Take the open covering of $\{\{x\},x\in \mathbb R\}$. Can you find a finite sub covering of it?