# why radius greater than $1$ includes the whole set?

Tags: general-topology

I have  some  confusion in this  question .

[example of a set that is closed and bounded but not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323033/example-of-a-set-that-is-closed-and-bounded-but-not-compact)

My confusion: why radius  greater than $1$ includes the  whole  set?   Here  $X=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N^+\right\}$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $B(x,r)$ where $r>1$. Take any $y$ in the space. Then $d(x,y)=0$ or $1$ so $d(x,y) <r$. Hence $y \in B(x,r)$. Thus $X \subset B(x,r)\subset X$ so $X=B(x,r)$.

Answer (score 1):

The distance from the center of the ball to any other point is $1$

Therefore if the radius of the ball is greater than $1$ then every point falls within the ball.